# how to automatically submit jar to hadoop via jobClient

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am currently using maven for dependencies management.

In this case, i wrote a method which commit a map-reduce job to hadoop, and then wrote a junit test for this method.

when i run `mvn package` it compiled successfully (all dependencies is correct) it is the unit test that failed.

on job tracker i can see a `ClassNotFoundException` indicates that my map, combine & reduce class is not found on node.

I dont wanna use `conf.setJar` to manually set a path for this jar file.

Is there any way to do this get this working automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mechanism by which your user code (mapper, combiner, reducer classes etc) can be made available to the TaskTrackers. This is typically handled by bundling your classes into a jar file and then using the `setJar` / `setJarByClass` methods. Behind the scenes, hadoop will then upload this jar to a tmp job directory in HDFS, and also add the tmp HDFS job jar to the distributed cache.

My advice would be to make your unit tests into integration tests - this phase in the maven lifecycle happens after package, and you'll have a jar by which you can then call setJar and know you'll have a jar built (I'm guessing here you don't wan to call setJar in the ordinary testing phase because the jar hasn't been built yet).

Finally if you want to test your mapper / reducer code without running in a real cluster you should look into [MRUnit](http://mrunit.apache.org/) or running the job in hadoop local mode - neither of which will require you to build a jar.

For reference, here's a minimal JUnit snippet for running in local mode that works on my Ubuntu desktop (you'll need either cygwin or unxutils installed if your desktop is windows). It's not a unit test as it doesn't assert the output:

```
@Test
public void testLocalRun() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,
            "src/test/java/csw/hadoop/sandbox/LocalHadoopTest.java");
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(
            "target/hadoop-local-output"));

    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks. when i marked these test as integration test, it works for me